# Call function from different sampler in JMeter - Groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have a sampler that get data from DB (budget), and I have some assertions that I made using JSR223 assertion.
In each assertion I write the same function (check_budget) and to each assertion I pass different values (start_budget, end_budget etc)

The problem is that I duplicate the code for each assertion and it is not friendly for maintenance.(if logic change need to change at 7 duplicate functions)
It there a way to create a sampler and write generic function in it (calc_budget) and to call it from each assertion,
like creating a class in java and perform import?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Groovy you have [`evaluate()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Script.html#evaluate(java.lang.String)) function, so given you stored it into a JMeter Variable or JMeter Property or into a file you can call it like:

```
evaluate(vars.get('your_var'))
```

or

```
evaluate(new File('your_test.groovy'))
```

See [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) article for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, and in general also, you can keep groovy script in a script file and call the same script file from all [JSR223 elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

> Script File
>   Name of a file to be used as a JSR223 script, if a relative file path is used, then it will be relative to directory referenced by "user.dir" System property